# i try to delete youtube video but it has "targetFeedReadOnly" error

Tags: objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

```
NSString *devKey = [mDeveloperKeyField text];
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];
[service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:(yotube e-mail account) password:(password)];

NSLog(@"%@",service.username);

NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForFeedID:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",url); //http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urlString,@"MooWz4o-NhE"];
[service deleteResourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] ETag:nil delegate:nil didFinishSelector:nil];
```

I make an effort above code has `"targetFeedReadOnly"` error.

What can i do?

Comment: library version is 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that you make a "GET" request to this url else if you use "POST" or "PUT" did not work...

Comment: change "GET" to "POST" and "targetfeedreadonly" error solved, but deleting video did not work..

Comment: @user3159713 your problem resolved accepted the answer. you have face any error